# Cancel a request without exiting the process

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js, I want to kill a particular process or request made by client without exiting the server.
I have used   `process.kill(process.pid, 0);`

But it ends the script for all processes. I want to kill or stop single process where at the same time other processes can continue execution.
actually my main problem is while uploading a file there are some data in pipe which continue coming after timeout and that makes the file corrupt. so I want to end that particular request so that it stops the data in pipe.

Is there any better way to do this ??

Comment: You want to cancel a request, not end a process. A request is not a process. Editend the question to reflect this.

Comment: This depends on the library you are using.

Comment: yes i want to end a particular request is there any way to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is "one-thread, one-process". Therefore if you kill the process, you kill the Node.js.

You cant kill request "inside Node.js" from "outside Node.js". It is similar as asking, if you can "kill the guy with sword" in prince of persia by command prompt.

For handling requests, you have to handle that inside Node.js with javascript code.